html file have something wrong Registration Form not submitting in Django
My html file have some issues but I can't figure it out what the problem actually is.
Can anyone Identify what really the problem is.
Here is Html I'm using:
signup.html
{% include "user/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Sign Up</h1>

<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" value="Register Account">


</form>

{% endblock %}

**views.py
**
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from . forms import create_user
# Create your views here.

def sign_up(request):
    form = create_user()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("test-home")
    
    
    
    context = {"form":form}
    return render(request, "user/signup.html", context)

**urls.py
**
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("create/", views.sign_up, name="sign_up"),
]


I have tried some other html sign up templates from other videos. Only copying them works. I can't figure out where the real problem is.

In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

You can not validate the create_user() form without binding it to the data:
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = create_user(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('test-home')
    else:
        form = create_user()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'user/signup.html', context)
I would however strongly advise not to name your form create_user. Typically a class is written in PascalCase, and a form has a …Form suffix, so CreateUserForm for example.
